# Adding a new Button on release of another button in Kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy, bind

I'm trying to have a button where if it is clicked it will insert a new button. I cant get the bind to return the new button.

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class app(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        button1 =Button(text="test",pos=(385,450),size_hint=(.1,.1))
        button1.bind(on_release=self.btn2)
        layout.add_widget(button1)
        return layout

    def btn2(self, event):
        print "worked"
        layout = FloatLayout()
        btn3 = Button(text="worked",size=(.1,.1),pos=(380,400))
        layout.add_widget(btn3)
        return layout

app().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating another instance of `FloatLayout` in the `btn2` event with **`layout = FloatLayout()`**, however that instance isn't anywhere else, but in the `btn2` method - i.e. you added a `Button` to `FloatLayout`, but that layout isn't visible and after the function ends it's highly possible that even doesn't exist, because it's garbage-collected by Python.

You can either use [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to pass the already existing instance of `FloatLayout` (where your previous `Button` is) like this if you need only one layout:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App

from functools import partial

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        button1 =Button(text="test",pos=(385,450),size_hint=(.1,.1))
        button1.bind(on_release=partial(self.btn2, layout))
        layout.add_widget(button1)
        return layout

    def btn2(self, layout, *args):
        print "worked"
        btn3 = Button(text="worked",size=(.1,.1),pos=(380,400))
        layout.add_widget(btn3)

app().run()
```

Or you can use the instance that's passed to method arguments from the event (the instance of a widget that dispatched the event):

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        button1 =Button(text="test",pos=(385,450),size_hint=(.1,.1))
        button1.bind(on_release=self.btn2)
        layout.add_widget(button1)
        return layout

    def btn2(self, button):
        layout = button.parent  # parent of the button is the "layout" from build()
        btn3 = Button(text="worked",size=(.1,.1),pos=(380,400))
        layout.add_widget(btn3)

app().run()
```

In both cases you only need to find the right instance to work with, not create another one that's not even used. Also `return layout` isn't necessary if you don't expect `on_release` to work with the `layout` variable (which it won't).